# Confluent schema registry vs Spring cloud schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I have been looking at spring cloud schema registry and confluent schema registry for now. I could see a few difference such as spring cloud schema registry saves schemas in normal database and by default in h2 whereas confluent schema registry is saved in kafka topic.

Is there any performance impact to this approach for spring cloud schema registry. As far as I understood even though the data is kept on topic in case of confluent there would still be a delay in querying it. But would there be a major impact?

Also I could see that spring cloud schema registry provides support for confluent schema registry, does that mean confluent schema registry is better?

Is there any fundamental difference in working of these schema registries?

What is the need for spring cloud schema registry if the confluent schema registry was already available?

Answer (score 2):

From a Spring Cloud Stream Kafka perspective, it is recommended to use the Confluent Schema Registry. It is fairly easy to integrate Spring Cloud Stream with Confluent Schema Registry. There are a few samples available [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/schema-registry-samples) demonstrating that. Spring Cloud Schema Registry is a project that is in maintenance mode and we may not add any further features to it. There is not much advantage of using Spring Cloud Schema registry if you are using Kafka. Spring Cloud Schema registry may become useful if you are performing schema evolution against a non-Kafka middleware system such as RabbitMQ, AWS Kinesis, etc. As you noted, by default it uses the `H2` database and you can configure it for other databases. If you find any issues with the integration between Spring Cloud Stream and Confluent Schema Registry, please raise them in the Kafka Binder [GH repository](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka).

Comment: is there any way to keep the data in  a topic in spring schema registry server just like confluent does rather than using other databases?

Comment: To ask a little bit more, is there any advantage that spring cloud schema registry provides over confluent schema registry. If you could add that to your answer it would be a lot useful.

Comment: From a Spring Cloud Stream Kafka perspective, it is recommended to use the Confluent Schema Registry - does he need to say more?

Comment: @RanLupovich Thanks for the reply. But when would be the best scenarios for to use spring cloud streams default schema registry compared to confluent schema registry