# Valdiate pojo using @Valid in sping cloud streams

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

How can one enable validation using **@Valid** inside the following kafka consumer code ? I am using **Spring Cloud Stream (Kafka Stream binder implementation)**, and there after my implemention is using functional model for example.

```
@Bean
public Consumer<KStream<String, @Valid Pojo>> process() {
    return messages -> messages.foreach((k, v) -> process(v));
}
```

I tried the following but it didn't work....

```
@Bean
public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory configureMessageHandlerMethodFactory(
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory,
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean) {       
    messageHandlerMethodFactory.setValidator(validatorFactoryBean);
    return messageHandlerMethodFactory;
}
```

This is simple in spring-kafka by implementing **KafkaListenerConfigurer** and setting **LocalValidatorFactoryBean** on **KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar**

```
public class KafkaConfiguration implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureKafkaListeners(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
  registrar.setValidator(validatorFactoryBean);
}
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in the functional model at the moment. Even for a non-functional scenario, this is non-trivial for types like `KStream`. The `KafkaListenerConfigurer` you mentioned above is for regular Kafka Support with a message channel binder. Your best options for Kafka Streams binder are either using some custom validation in the function itself before continuing with the processing or introducing a schema registry and then perform a schema validation before passing the record to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Soby, I became a bit optimistic on reading the following https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1382. Is this only for imperative programming model ? Further I am using apache kafka installation, unlike confluent version which provides schema registry. Is It possible to use schema registry with apache kafka ?

Comment: I believe you can use Confluent Schema Registry in standalone mode, although I am not sure about the details on how it is supported. You can also use Spring Cloud Schema Registry (which is in maintenance mode). See this answer I just posted on this topic. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68182678/2070861

Comment: Thanks once again Soby both you and Gary are always there answering our queries. I am grateful !!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the recommendation to create a bean that respects the functional interface of java, that is, it has only a public method, for example:

```
@Validated
@Component
public class Processor implements Consumer<KStream<String, Pojo>> {

    @Override
    public void accept(final @Valid @NotNull KStream<String, Pojo> stream) {
          stream.foreach((k, v) -> process(v));
    }

    private void process(final Pojo v) {
    }

}
```

> So that generates an execution:
> javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000151: A method
> overriding another method must not reset the parameter constraint
> configuration

It is not possible to overwrite the parameters of the accept method of the consumer functional interface so just remove the interface and leave the component like this:

```
@Validated
@Component
public class Processor {

     public void accept(final @Valid @NotNull KStream<String, Pojo> stream) {
          stream.foreach((k, v) -> process(v));
     }

     private void process(final Pojo v) {
     }

 }
```

The problem is that the spring cloud function will not recognize the bean for not extending one of the functional classes.

the workaround I got was:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class ValidatedEventListener<T> implements Consumer<T> {

    private final Validator validator;

    @Override
    public void accept(final T t) {
        validate(t);
        listen(t);
    }

    public abstract void listen(final T t);

    public void validate(final Object event) {
        var violations = validator.validate(event);
        if (!violations.isEmpty()) throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
    }

}
```